# How Do I get rid of XCode Architecture link errors?

Tags: xcode, architecture, compiler-construction, warnings

I am building a Maya App in XCode(3.2.6) for the Mac. I am building my own libs that I link to, and additionally I am linking with some Maya libs that are included with the application. Maya is 64-bit, it seems, and when I run file from terminal on one of the dylibs I need to link to it says "64-bit dynamically linked shard library x86_64". That's all fine and I can build all of my projects.

However, I get a ton of warnings that all say something like:

```
...dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

I get one for each lib I am linking to, including the ones I have built. I have a strange suspicion that this warning is a serious one and that it is affecting their usability. Maya is unable to load my top level bundle and I am guessing it is because of this warning. At the very least, it would be nice to get rid of them because, coming from Windows, it sounds very bad. All of my project settings are generally the same for the "Architectures" setting. My "Architectures" is just set to "64-bit Intel" and my "Valid Architectures" is set to "ppc64 x86_64". I previously had my latter argument include more as "i386 ppc ppc64 ppc7400 ppc970 x86_64" but that wasn't working either. I have tried tons of different settings but no luck getting rid of those warnings.

I guess my question is: what determines the "architecture being linked"? Where is the i386 warning coming from? It doesn't seem to be a project setting. Does this sound like something that could shoot me in the foot down the line?  Any suggestions for getting rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

`i386` is 32 bit x86. You need to make sure that all the libraries you build are `x86-64`. Note that checking the project settings may not be sufficient, as the architecture can be overridden at the **target** level, so you need to check the architecture for each target too.

Comment: Ok...So I removed all of the unnecessary libs from my project.  All of the remaining ones (Only 4) are x86_64 and I checked that using the "file" command.  Also, the libs I have generated are x86_64.  My architecture is set to x86_64 as well but I still get the warnings.  Otherwise, the only other components I have are zlib.dylib (standard Mac compression lib) and four other frameworks (Carbon, IO, GLUT, and OpenGL).  Do you know what could be giving me the i386??  Thanks Paul.

Comment: @Erik: you need to check the error messages to see what the remaining libs are which have the wrong architecture

Comment: Paul...Thanks for helping again.  The libs I create are x86_64.  Also, the other libs I link to are x86_64.  For both the targets and the project, I have "Valid Architectures" set to ppc64 and x86_64 and "Architectures" set to 64-bit Intel.  I have cleaned the solution and rebuilt many times.  I checked zlib, and it seems that Mac has three different versions based on Architectures that people may need.  However I still get warnings for the libs that they are "not the architecture being linked(i386)".

Comment: I have tried to remove anything that may be bringing that in including checking all of the properties for both the project and the targets.  Obviously something is still bringing those in but I don't know what.  Could it be the frameworks?  I am stumped.  The libs seem to be the correct one.  I think the problem is more that somehow the "Architecture being linked" is i386 unless I am misunderstanding the error.  I just don't know what determines it.  Like you mentioned before, something seems to be overriding the setting.  Again, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Had to go two comments to get it in...Sorry.

Comment: @Erik: one thing you need to be aware of is that paths to places like `/usr/lib` *et al* are actually routed through your SDK setting. So what you think of as `/usr/lib` is typically e.g. `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib` (assuming you have your SDK set to 10.6). This can make life confusing when switching between Xcode's "world view" and where you might expect to find libraries etc.

Comment: Ahhh it was a very stupid mistake indeed.  I am working with legacy projects and I guess I didn't check to see that the PreProcessor flag dialog could be expanded.  I should have looked at the command line build instructions from the get go.  Basically the architecture was being hard coded to i386.  Thanks for the help Paul I really appreciate you taking the time to comment.  Mistakes like these are the ones you learn the most from unfortunately.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Erik: glad you got it sorted - it's always the silly little problems that take the most time to track down !